# summarising a 3 months sales report across 2 branches into top 3 product for each month

Tags: sql, oracle, querying

I have the following REPORT table

```
m = month,
pid = product_id,
bid = branch_id,
s = sales

m       pid     bid     s
--------------------------
1       1       1       20
1       3       1       11
1       2       1       14
1       4       1       16
1       5       1       31
1       1       2       30
1       3       2       10
1       2       2       24
1       4       2       17
1       5       2       41
2       3       1       43
2       5       1       21
2       4       1       10
2       1       1       5
2       2       1       12
2       3       2       22
2       5       2       10
2       4       2       5
2       1       2       4
2       2       2       10
3       3       1       21
3       5       1       10
3       4       1       44
3       1       1       4
3       2       1       14
3       3       2       10
3       5       2       5
3       4       2       6
3       1       2       7
3       2       2       10
```

I'd like to have a summary of this sales table
by showing the top 3 sales among the products across all branches.
something like this:

```
m       pid     total
---------------------
1       5       72
1       1       50
1       4       33
2       3       65
2       5       31
2       2       22
3       4       50
3       3       31
3       2       24
```

so on month 1, product #5 has the highest total sales with 72, followed by product #1 is 50.. and so on. if i could separate them into different table for each month would be better

so far what i can do is make a summary for 1 month and shows the entire thing and not top 3.

```
select pid, sum(s)
from report
where m = 1
group by pid
order by sum(s);
```

thanks a lot!

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: oracle 11g at the university's lab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most databases support the ANSI standard window functions.  You can do what you want with `row_number()`:

```
select m, pid, s
from (select r.m, r.pid, sum(s) as s,
             row_number() over (partition by m order by sum(s) desc) as seqnum
      from report r
      group by r.m, r.pid
     ) r
where seqnum <= 3
order by m, s desc;
```

Comment: Hi thanks, it works, some modification I made:
1) add a "," at the end of line 2, maybe it's oracle requirements. 
2) remove the "pid" on the last line so just "order by m, s desc;"

the output so far looks okay here.
What do you think?